clickhouse, get headers and meta from AvroConfluent message
I have a kafka topic in the AvroConfluent format, I can take data from messages, but only from the fields that are in the format_avro_schema_registry_url, previously the data format was JSONEachRow and the meta with headers was taken from the same message. Is it possible to take meta and headers from messages in AvroConfluent format, or do I need to put them inside values on kafka side?
clickhouse version 22.8.9.24

This is a best idea to change messages format in the same kafka topic,
better use different topic
according to https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/formats#data-format-avro-confluent, AvroConfluent messages will parse only with schema registry

hi @Zaoza14 - what are you using to load data into ClickHouse from Kafka please? This will help formulate a better answer. Thanks
